# Passing Material UI components as props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to pass material UI icons from Sidebar.js to SidebarOption. The idea is to display sidebar options in sidebar passing in different MUI icons.

Sidebar.js

```
import React from "react";
import TwitterIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Twitter";
import SidebarOption from "./SidebarOption.js";

function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <SidebarOption Icon={TwitterIcon} text="Home" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

SidebarOption.js

```
import React from "react";

function SidebarOption({ text, Icon }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon />
      <h2>{text}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SidebarOption;
```

I got the error below. Icon is the problem. text works fine..

[image: error message]

Comment: @0stone0 no it doesnt solve the problem

Comment: I was following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJjaqSTzOxI (46:06 min)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material UI - passing icon as a prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587636/material-ui-passing-icon-as-a-prop)

Answer (score 4):

Try passing it as `<SidebarOption Icon={<TwitterIcon />} text="Home" />` and using it as `{Icon}` in SidebarOption.js

Comment: wow! it works! but any clue why this works. my way doesn't work? (i copied it from the tutorials)

Comment: Thats literally the comment I places from which you said it didn't work ;)

Comment: sorry!. i didn't realize it has to be called using {Icon}, i only changed the first half...any clue why my way doesn't work?  @0stone0

Comment: Ahh sorry, should have included that in my comment. You weren't passing the component, but using the props like it was. Now you're just passing the component, and using the prop as it's given. The marked duplicate seems exact like your question. Please consider marking as dupplicate.

Comment: Works for me !!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. Make sure the [peer dependencies](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/398684450a89ef2cf167d56be3e1a95ea1763f7a/packages/material-ui-icons/package.json#L56-L60) for `@material-ui/icons` are installed: specifically, check for `@material-ui/core`, which is where that Twitter component comes from.