# Mapping Horizontal divider using Material UI react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on menu component storybook where i have mapped icon & text , problem is i have horizontal divider in between , how do i Map it with icons & text.From below code i'm getting divider at the bottom of the Menu. I'm trying to achieve as it is in the image. In the storybook i have to map few menu variants as in mui, for that i cannot hardcode divider, if there is any way i can manage it with Map or any other method.  Thanks.

[image]

```
 export const Menu= ({ icons }) => {
    return (
        <Paper sx={{ width: 320, maxWidth: '100%' }} >

            <MenuList>
                {icons.map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem>
                        <ListItemIcon fontSize="small">{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText>{item.label}</ListItemText>
                        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">{item.typography}</Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
                <Divider /> /* how do i map this */
            </MenuList>
        </Paper >
    );
}
```

**Stories.js**

```
icons: [
        { icon: <ContentCut fontSize="small" />, typography: "⌘X", label: "Cut" },
        { icon: <ContentCopy fontSize="small" />, typography: "⌘C", label: "Copy" },       
    ]
```

Comment: Hello there to make sure i understand you correctly , you want to map over ```<ContentCopy/>``` as Material UI icons are imported that way am i correct ? , i never really used ```.map()``` method to map over components i usually use it to map over properties Like this example ```function HomeIcon(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}``` Where we can map over the colors props not the home icon itself check the docs https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#svgicon , are you able to use a different icon library?

Comment: yeah, i'm working on storybook , where user can change the data according to their requirement. so wanted to map divider same as i did for icons & label. If i hardcode like above , i'm getting divider at the end of menu. Thanks

Comment: Your most welcome , may i ask you did my sandbox include everything and answered your question?

Comment: Where's the image ?

Comment: was correcting forgot to add it again.Added it,

Answer (score 2):

***Answer:***
If you want the divider to be just one then don't map over it . thats the purpose of the `.map()` method.
and To Acheive the required results i just removed `<Menu></Menu>` Component and Just Kept the `<Papper></Papper>` Component

***Notes :***

1. In terms of how to Map the Divider with the below example ,you can just wrap it in a empty react fragment`<></>`  and map over the `<MenuItem></MenuItem>` .
2. Only issue is that youll get an error in your `key` props which will say its not unique  it can be fixed by assigning `index` key like the example below and wrap the `<MenuItem></MenuItem>` Component in It. However thats not best practice ,
3. `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` Is better practice according to [Keyed Fragment React 18 Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments) to add a `key` prop However that's giving a  New Error in MUI.
4. Thats not an issue since were mapping over the `MenuItem` Component , However if we use for example in @Nathan Comments  `<React.Fragment key={index}></React.Fragment>` or my previous answer to use `<></>` we would be mapping over the `React.Fragment` Itself or the empty fragment and would get a new error `MUI: The Menu component doesn't accept a Fragment as a child.` Uncomment the Examples in the Sandbox Check the sandbox console.

Check Code [Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-18-material-ui-icons-mapping-and-divider-6plbpi?file=/index.js)

Solution

```
         export const MenuIcon = ({ menuicons }) => {
                return (
             <Paper sx={{ width: 320, maxWidth: "100%" }}>
      {menuicons.map((item, index) => (
        <MenuItem key={item + index}>
          <ListItemIcon fontSize="small">{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>{item.label}</ListItemText>
    
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            {item.typography}
          </Typography>
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    
      <Divider />
      <ListItemIcon fontSize="small">
        ClipBoard <ContentCopyIcon fontSize="small" />
      </ListItemIcon>
    </Paper>
                );
            }
```

[image]

***References***

[Empty Fragment Syntax React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax)

[Stack OverFlow Question MUI Icons - as props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587636/material-ui-passing-icon-as-a-prop)

[.map() method Syntax - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax)

Comment: i'm getting horizontal divider below each row.  As i want  only one as shared the image . thanks

Comment: Ok sorry didnt get you the first time!

Comment: I'm trying to achieve as it is in material UI . shared the image , as per your we are bit close .Please help. Thanks

Comment: No Problem At all mate trying my best here you can check https://mui.com/material-ui/react-divider/#main-content to check for a solution with me i am just currently trying to adapt my existing sandbox for your requirement

Comment: Updated my answer check it out now if that suits your requirements!!!

Comment: No, its not working. If i add 2 more rows to menu. divider is after each row.

Comment: you want the divider just for the clipboard , then dont map over it thats the purpose of ```.map()``` method btw Check the code sandbox and answer now.

Comment: means it cannot be achieved with mapping ? Thanks for the answer, if that is the ultimate solution :)

Comment: no man its not that its used to map over and iterate over values not single values  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map Check MDN Docs and Btw their is no ultimate solution man this is meant just to help your reach your questions solution not an ultimate answer if your not satisifed with the answer i am just a user at the end of the day i could just remove my answer for other people to do so , no hard feelings i am just trying to help :)

Comment: I didnt mean to offend you. I apologize if i did so. I'm really grateful for your time & answers you provided. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No Problem at all do you want me to remove my answer mate so other people could see it as unanswered ? therefore you'll get other answers , here is another tip using .map with single values ```Using parseInt() with map()``` try it but it does bring undesired and weird behavior to mapping.

Comment: no , i'll go with your last answer , i'll remove clipboard from mapping. it really did help me . Thanks

Comment: no problem at all mate , love and peace to you and good luck on your project !!!

Comment: fyi for anyone reading this, you can't add key to an empty fragment `<>`, but you *can* add it to a `React.Fragment`, e.g., `<React.Fragment key={index}>`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390967/954986) for details.

Comment: Will update will my answer accordingly thank you ! <3

Comment: unfortunately for MUI you cant assign a ```<React.Fragment key={index}>``` Or ```<></>``` you gell get a new ERROR ```MUI: The Menu component doesn't accept a Fragment as a child.``` Ill Update my Answer accordingly